# Как узнать, откуда грузится debian? Как объединить разделы и не затереть загрузочный сектор?

Tags: linux, debian

Есть два диска по 3.84ТБ ssd в рейде и HDD на 8 TB. Изначально на автомате на хезнере, насколько помню, система была установлена на HDD, потом переустановлена на SSD. Ниже что осталось. Как узнать, откуда грузится debian? Как объединить разделы и не затереть загрузочный сектор? Я вижу BIOS boot и на /dev/sda5 - а это HDD. Конечная цель - примонтировать HDD в папку. Для этого, я так понимаю, надо объединить все разделы /dev/sda?

```
fdisk -l
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 3.5 TiB, 3840755982336 bytes, 7501476528 sectors
Disk model: SAMSUNG MZQLB3T8HALS-00007
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: C3D50790-812F-4B14-9AA0-A57AA316DD24

Device           Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    4096    1052671    1048576  512M Linux RAID
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1052672 7501476494 7500423823  3.5T Linux RAID
/dev/nvme0n1p3    2048       4095       2048    1M BIOS boot

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 3.5 TiB, 3840755982336 bytes, 7501476528 sectors
Disk model: SAMSUNG MZQLB3T8HALS-00007
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 7CCCAAEA-4191-4261-9324-9E5270CAF93D

Device           Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme1n1p1    4096    1052671    1048576  512M Linux RAID
/dev/nvme1n1p2 1052672 7501476494 7500423823  3.5T Linux RAID
/dev/nvme1n1p3    2048       4095       2048    1M BIOS boot

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/md0: 511 MiB, 535822336 bytes, 1046528 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/md1: 3.5 TiB, 3840081723392 bytes, 7500159616 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 7.3 TiB, 8001563222016 bytes, 15628053168 sectors
Disk model: HGST HUH721008AL
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D89378D7-4DA0-4619-9379-3942FD7E44D6

Device          Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1        4096     8392703     8388608    4G Linux RAID
/dev/sda2     8392704     9441279     1048576  512M Linux RAID
/dev/sda3     9441280  2121273343  2111832064 1007G Linux RAID
/dev/sda4  2121273344 15628053134 13506779791  6.3T Linux RAID
/dev/sda5        2048        4095        2048    1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda6          34        2047        2014 1007K Linux filesystem

Partition 6 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/mapper/vg0-root: 3.5 TiB, 3822898380800 bytes, 7466598400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/vg0-swap: 16 GiB, 17179869184 bytes, 33554432 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Вывод mount:

```
mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime,hidepid=2)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=65948908k,nr_inodes=16487227,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=13200064k,mode=755)
/dev/mapper/vg0-root on / type ext4 (rw,relatime)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
bpf on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=30,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=18094)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
/dev/md0 on /boot type ext3 (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/0 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=13200060k,mode=700)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/debug/tracing type tracefs (rw,relatime)
```

Вывод blkid

```
blkid
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="68abe8ed-df01-2437-60ad-e590f978fb53" UUID_SUB="8c925784-41ed-6d57-7e2b-f36857c73756" LABEL="rescue:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="f2d46540-8f5d-4b8d-931f-6a6d1f8b24c6"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="c0a9dabe-d659-7acc-4518-ecf673203798" UUID_SUB="f1cbd994-3df4-517f-4960-5465feb34e2a" LABEL="rescue:1" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="47ed442c-1018-48c8-830e-e1cf128df213"
/dev/nvme1n1p1: UUID="68abe8ed-df01-2437-60ad-e590f978fb53" UUID_SUB="c2896239-cc74-b870-80a5-cbaf07bba220" LABEL="rescue:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="eed45954-0920-43bf-86b1-daa8b17e3992"
/dev/nvme1n1p2: UUID="c0a9dabe-d659-7acc-4518-ecf673203798" UUID_SUB="dae94270-cf3b-1a4a-5230-640027c587a3" LABEL="rescue:1" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="0b7fa512-582d-4bf5-bf3e-c40b221ea1b9"
/dev/md0: UUID="9bc8c266-4123-41de-a12d-65be5f2575f3" TYPE="ext3"
/dev/md1: UUID="rS4JHd-ZlLs-rACu-iCgD-6LcC-zOJ4-AJhAGM" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/sda1: UUID="1821272e-a5bb-ca0b-ed93-d5002e5ee229" UUID_SUB="e9fdd127-11f6-3284-3fd4-95a719a9650b" LABEL="rescue:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="f9931e5a-56ad-4c03-9358-5127d072eaf3"
/dev/sda2: UUID="661587f0-5cb6-41d2-7027-e2835c046d29" UUID_SUB="dc3ed50b-3992-8c06-eb33-0162510b9209" LABEL="rescue:1" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="e222a552-22c9-4838-b513-3b542ff853a9"
/dev/sda3: UUID="52205238-d49a-875b-bd51-059def189548" UUID_SUB="26402841-9420-ec44-615e-528053ccbe0b" LABEL="rescue:2" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="c0b70a2c-802c-4462-96dd-3f6b8c424f44"
/dev/sda4: UUID="4c43f6eb-d2e4-116f-64c5-c9744ac8a17c" UUID_SUB="9cb70f08-2233-003e-d90f-99d3ed65405d" LABEL="rescue:3" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="73f25706-4947-474b-bd65-c7897eb3149e"
/dev/mapper/vg0-root: UUID="34d0cd54-029d-454b-8d0a-670aca965514" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/nvme0n1: PTUUID="c3d50790-812f-4b14-9aa0-a57aa316dd24" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: PARTUUID="118c0cf7-48bc-4dc3-9dfd-fc2e2c2bbde0"
/dev/nvme1n1: PTUUID="7cccaaea-4191-4261-9324-9e5270caf93d" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/nvme1n1p3: PARTUUID="d092f6b6-b983-4a4f-9136-73e3c4f8bf15"
/dev/sda5: PARTUUID="18f45c00-47d6-41e8-afec-00b304372d51"
/dev/sda6: UUID="078f2861-9aff-4bb2-9424-44dd5621e41a" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="16efc9de-9783-0443-96df-9aa848141660"
/dev/mapper/vg0-swap: UUID="96b81d52-e6d9-42f9-a611-c4edb16a2408" TYPE="swap"
```

Comment: Выхлопы `blkid` и `mount` добавь.

Comment: У вас там полно разделов с меткой RAID на этом диске, а на других разделах LVM накатан. Вы разберитесь с текущим положением вещей, опишите уровни RAID, и как организован LVM.

Comment: Добавил выхлопы blkid и mount

Comment: @0andriy на ssd raid, сверху накатан LVM. Добавил выхлопы blkid и mount. Еще нужна какая-то информация?

Comment: _/proc/mdstat_ если я правильно помню название файла. У вас загрузка из каталога _/boot_, который на md0. Хотя более точно надо смотреть конфигурацию загрузчика, потому как загрузка ядра и начального образа может происходить с чего угодно.